# When does $B^x \equiv B^{2^{2^i}}\ (\textrm{mod}\ N)$ imply $(B^x)^x \equiv B^{2^{2^{i+1}}}\ (\textrm{mod}\ N)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

If $B^x \equiv B^{2^{2^i}}\ (\textrm{mod}\ N)$, under what conditions must it be true that $(B^x)^x \equiv B^{2^{2^{i+1}}}\ (\textrm{mod}\ N)$?

We can take for granted that $N$ is the product of two large and distinct primes $p$ and $q$, $\gcd(B, N) = 1$, and $B > 1$. What must also be true? Do $p$ and $q$ each have to be safe primes (i.e. they are each the product of 2 and another large prime)? What if $p \equiv q \equiv 3\ (\textrm{mod}\ 4)$? What if $B$ is a quadratic residue $(\textrm{mod}\ N)$, such as $4$?

This is confusing to me, partly because $\gcd(2, \phi(N)) > 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note the following:

**Claim 1:** *If the equation $A \equiv_N B$ holds [$A,B$ nonnegative integers, $N$ a positive integers] then for any nonnegative integer $y$ so does the equation $A^y \equiv_N B^y$.*

Raise then, both sides of the equation by $x$ and use Claim 1 to
$$B^x \equiv_N B^{2^{2^i}}$$ to conclude
$$(B^x)^x \equiv_N \ \big(B^{2^{2^i}}\big)^x.$$
But then
$$\big(B^{2^{2^i}}\big)^x = B^{x\times2^{2^i}} = (B^x)^{2^{2^i}}$$
$$\equiv_N \big(B^{2^{2^i}}\big)^{2^{2^i}} = B^{2^{2^{i}} \times 2^{2^i}} = B^{2^{2^{i+1}}},$$
where the third-to-last last relation $(B^x)^{2^{2^i}} \equiv_N \big(B^{2^{2^i}}\big)^{2^{2^i}}$ follows from the equation $B^x \equiv_N B^{2^{2^{i}}}$ and Claim 1. So in particular,
$$\big(B^{2^{2^i}}\big)^x \equiv_N B^{2^{2^{i+1}}}.$$ Thus, concluding:
$$(B^x)^x =B^{x^2} \equiv_N \ \big(B^{2^{2^i}}\big)^x \equiv_N B^{2^{2^{i+1}}},$$ or to sum up
$$B^{x^2} \equiv_N B^{2^{2^{i+1}}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

The two numbers are the same, you don't require the modulo.

On one side, we have:
\begin{align}
2^{i+1}&=2^i2\\
2^{2^{i+1}}&=2^{2^i2}\\
&=\left(2^{2^i}\right)^2
\end{align}
So
$$B^{2^{2^{i+1}}}=B^{\left(2^{2^i}\right)^2}$$
Let's say $x=2^{2^i}$, which leaves us
\begin{align}
B^{2^{2^{i+1}}}&=B^{x^2}\\
&=\left(B^x\right)^x
\end{align}

Comment: Well but can you say $x=2^{2^i}$ though? For each positive integer $a$, in particular $a=2^{2^i}$, there are infinitely many positive integers $x$ such that $B^x=B^a$.

Comment: Indeed, I misread. The statement $B^x\equiv B^y$ doesn't imply $(B^x)^x\equiv (B^y)^y$, which is equivalent to the statement above for $y=2^{2^i}$.

Comment: @Mike Right, this makes it complicated.